# Leetcode, Shuffle the Array, what's wrong with my answer?

Tags: java, arrays, pointers

**The Problem**:
Given the array nums consisting of 2n elements in the form [x1,x2,...,xn,y1,y2,...,yn].

Return the array in the form [x1,y1,x2,y2,...,xn,yn].

I figured I could copy the first half in one array, the second half in another, and take turns putting them in a new array but I'm getting the error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3"... What can I do to fix that error?

The hint said I could use pointers, but what was wrong with the way I thought of going about it?

**Here's my code**:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] shuffle(int[] nums, int n) {
        int[] first = new int[n];
        int[] second = new int[n];
        int[] ans = new int[n+n];
        System.arraycopy(nums, 0, first, 0, n);
        System.arraycopy(nums, n + 1, second, 0, n - 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < (nums.length); i++){
            ans[i] = first[i]; //GETTING ERROR HERE
            ans[i + 1] = second[i];
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to become a professional software developer, or regularly develop software, you will need to have debugging skills. And, this is a good problem to practice debugging  on. An IDE usually will have a debugger tool. It will allow you to set a break point, and then follow the code step-by-step, while monitoring the values of variables.

Comment: When referencing tasks that have web pages, such as problems from coding challenge and practice sites, please include a link to the page in the question.  For reference, the LeetCode page seems to be this one:  https://leetcode.com/problems/shuffle-the-array/

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `n`.  It isn't defined in the question.

Comment: @WJS "Given the array nums consisting of **2n** elements"

Comment: Off-topic: After you solve your current problem, see if you can think of a way to do this without creating intermediate arrays, such as `first` or `second`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)  You can also [search for other Java questions about `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+arrayindexoutofboundsexception)`

Answer (score 1):

You get this exception because `nums.length` is two times `n`, so the index goes out of bounds when `i` reaches `n`.

You could solve this with just one loop of `n` iterations:

```java
public int[] shuffle(int[] nums, int n) {
    int[] ans = new int[2 * n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ans[i * 2] = nums[i];
        ans[i * 2 + 1] = nums[n + i];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At ans[i + 1] For i= (length of the array-1 ).you are assigning it to ans array .Since the indies starts from 0 ,at ans[n] there won’t be any assignment and the index will be out of bound.Solution is to run the loop n-2 times only

Answer (score 0):

The array `nums` is of size `2n` whereas `first` and `second` are of size `n`. Let's say `nums` has a size of 100, then `first` and `second` will have a size of 50. At some point your loop is trying to access indices that don't exist in `first` and `second`.

Also, you're going to have an exception in the next line too, since `ans[i+1]` will eventually try to access the index 100, being the maximum 99.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your parameters for the *second* *arraycopy* are incorrect.

Consider the following; where *n* is *5*.

```java
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
int[] second = new int[n];
System.arraycopy(nums, n + 1, second, 0, n - 1);
```

Output

```
[7, 8, 9, 0, 0]
```

The *srcPos* and *length* parameter should both be *n*.

```java
System.arraycopy(nums, n, second, 0, n);
```

Output

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

> *"... I'm getting the error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3"... What can I do to fix that error? ..."*

You can utilize two *loop* parameters.
One to hold the index for the *first* and *second* array, and one to hold the index of the *ans* array.

```java
public static int[] shuffle(int[] nums, int n) {
    int[] first = new int[n];
    int[] second = new int[n];
    int[] ans = new int[n+n];
    System.arraycopy(nums, 0, first, 0, n);
    System.arraycopy(nums, n, second, 0, n);
    for(int indexA = 0, indexB = 0; indexA < n; indexA++, indexB += 2){
        ans[indexB] = first[indexA];
        ans[indexB + 1] = second[indexA];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Output

```
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 0]
```